# How to change an img with text in innerHTML

Tags: javascript, html

This is just a part of the code:

```
<div id="login">
    <form id="form" method="post" action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>">
        <h1 id="heade">Register!</h1>
        <input type="text" id="username" name="username" placeholder="username (6-55char)" class="reqi">
        <input type="password" id="password" name="password" placeholder="password (6-55char)" class="reqi">
        <input type="password" id="passwordconfirmation" name="passwordconfirmation" placeholder="confirm password" class="reqi">
        <input type="text" id="email" name="email" placeholder="e-mail adress" class="reqi">
        <p id="req">Enter the Captcha code:</p>
        <h1 id="captcha"><img src="http://i.imgur.com/QgoRq4h.gif" alt="loading"></h1>
        <input type="text" id="code" name="code"><br>
        <div id="buttons">
            <input type="submit" id="submit">
            <button type="button" onclick="login()">Back to Log In</button>
        </div>
        <p><?php echo $txt; ?></p>
    </form>
</div>
<script>
    var captcha =<?php echo $_SESSION['final']; ?>;
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("captcha").innerHTML = captcha;
    }, 3000);
    function login() {
        window.location = "main.php";
    }
</script>
```

After waiting for 3 seconds the page doesn't change the image from the h1 with `id="captcha" with the varaible captcha which by the way isn't null (I checked). I need a solution in javascript, as I don't know jQuery yet. Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Its not full snippet of code. What is in $_SESSION['final'] ? 
Probably you get javascript errors in console.

That line:

```
var captcha=<?php echo $_SESSION['final']; ?>;
```

Produces syntax error like:

```
var captcha=XXXX;
```

Try to change it to:

```
var captcha="<?php echo $_SESSION['final']; ?>";
```

Answer (score 0):

```
setTimeout(function() {
    var e = document.getElementsById('captcha');
    var d = document.createElement('span');

    d.textContent = captcha;

    e.appendChild(d);
    e.removeChild(e);
}, 3000);
```